# How to convert Double to Int in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to figure out how I can get my program to lose the `.0` after an integer when I don't need the any decimal places.

```
@IBOutlet weak var numberOfPeopleTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var amountOfTurkeyLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var cookTimeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var thawTimeLabel: UILabel!

var turkeyPerPerson = 1.5
var hours: Int = 0
var minutes = 0.0

func multiply (#a: Double, b: Double) -> Double {
    return a * b
}

func divide (a: Double , b: Double) -> Double {
    return a / b
}

@IBAction func calculateButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    var numberOfPeople = numberOfPeopleTextField.text.toInt()
    var amountOfTurkey = multiply(a: 1.5, b: Double(numberOfPeople!))
    var x: Double = amountOfTurkey
    var b: String = String(format:"%.1f", x)
    amountOfTurkeyLabel.text = "Amount of Turkey: " + b + "lbs"
    
    var time = multiply(a: 15, b:  amountOfTurkey)
    var x2: Double = time
    var b2: String = String(format:"%.1f", x2)
    if (time >= 60) {
        time = time - 60
        hours = hours + 1
        minutes = time
        var hours2: String = String(hours)
        var minutes2: String = String(format: "%.1f", minutes)
        
        cookTimeLabel.text = "Cook Time: " + hours2 + " hours and " + minutes2 + " minutes"
    } else {
        cookTimeLabel.text = "Cook Time: " + b2 + "minutes"
    }
   
}
```

Do I need to make an if statement to somehow turn Double into Int for this to work?

Comment: use the toInt() Funktion like NAME OF THE DOUBLEVALUE.?toInt()

Answer (score 159, accepted):

You can use:

```
Int(yourDoubleValue)
```

this will convert double to int.

or when you use String format use 0 instead of 1:

```
String(format: "%.0f", yourDoubleValue)
```

this will just display your Double value with no decimal places, without converted it to int.

Comment: This is not good approach and it will crash if it exceeds boundaries of `Int`. Eg. `Int(Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude)`

Comment: Echoing Tomas Linhart.  This approach is not safe.  Example: `Int(Double.infinity) // crashes`

Answer (score 61):

It is better to verify a size of `Double` value before you convert it otherwise it could crash.

```
extension Double {
    func toInt() -> Int? {
        if self >= Double(Int.min) && self < Double(Int.max) {
            return Int(self)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

The crash is easy to demonstrate, just use `Int(Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude)`.

Comment: `Int(exactly:)` will fail to convert `Double` values that can't be exactly converted to an integer. E.g., `Int(exactly: 3.1)` will return `nil`.

Comment: @IsaacOveracker You are right, it was incorrect information. I removed it.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `>=` and `<=` is more correct, no?

Comment: @BaseZen No. :-) That will crash.

Comment: @TomášLinhart The rounding crash is only on the positive side, where the -1 offset causes trouble. `Double` can represent 2^63 exactly or 9223372036854775808 (one too high) or 9223372036854774784 (511 too low) but not anywhere in between. However 2^-63 is exact in both representations (binary in both after all) and `>=` indeed works.

Comment: Or just cast to Int64 with `Int64(myDouble)`

Comment: This formula is correct on 64-bit platforms but not optimal on 32-bit platforms like watchOS... because there, `Double(Int32.max).toInt()` will return nil instead of 2147483647 (`Int32(Double(Int32.max))`) since it's equal to `Double(Int.max)` on that platform.

Comment: I wonder why would Apple leave a initialiser for Int(Double) if that can cause crash? They could at least put a warning in documentation or make it return optional value...

Answer (score 8):

that should work:

```swift
// round your double so that it will be exactly-convertible
if let converted = Int(exactly: double.rounded()) {
  doSomethingWithInteger(converted)
} else {
  // double wasn't convertible for a reason, it probably overflows
  reportAnError("\(double) is not convertible")
}
```

`init(exactly:)` is almost the same with `init(:)`, the only difference is that `init(exactly:)` doesn't crash while `init(:)` may call `fatalError(:)` in case of failure.

You can check their implementations here

- [`init(:)`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Integers.swift#L3054)
- [`init(exactly:)`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Integers.swift#L3080)

Answer (score 7):

Another way:

```
extension Double {
    
    func toInt() -> Int? {
        let roundedValue = rounded(.toNearestOrEven)
        return Int(exactly: roundedValue)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A more generic way to suppress (only) the .0 decimal place in a string representation of  a `Double` value is to use `NSNumberFormatter`. It considers also the number format of the current locale.

```
let x : Double = 2.0
let doubleAsString = NumberFormatter.localizedString(from: (NSNumber(value: x), numberStyle: .decimal) 
// --> "2"
```

Comment: Current right way: NumberFormatter.localizedString(from: NSNumber(value:self), number: .decimal)

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4 - Xcode 9

```
let value = doubleToInteger(data:"ENTER DOUBLE VALUE")

func doubleToInteger(data:Double)-> Int {
    let doubleToString = "\(data)"
    let stringToInteger = (doubleToString as NSString).integerValue
            
    return stringToInteger
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert double to NSNumber
2. Use .int64Value var for Int64 and .intValue for Int
3. I am storing long int values like timestamp so
   using Int64 for precision

Note:

> Conversion from double to Int and Int(someDouble) can give you an
> exception error on range exceed case So using Int64(someDouble) and
> Int(someDouble) is both not suitable whereas NSNumber(floatLiteral:
> value_InDouble).intValue will not give you any such error.

```
  let value_Int64 = NSNumber(floatLiteral: value_InDouble).int64Value

OR

  let value_Int = NSNumber(floatLiteral: value_InDouble).intValue
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4 - Xcode 10**

Use this code to avoid a crash if the double value exceeds the int boundaries (and so isn't representable):

Add this private extension to your class:

```
private extension Int {

    init?(doubleVal: Double) {
        guard (doubleVal <= Double(Int.max).nextDown) && (doubleVal >= Double(Int.min).nextUp) else {
        return nil
    }

    self.init(doubleVal)
}
```

Use the extension in your class this way:

```
func test() {

    let d = Double(123.564)
    guard let intVal = Int(doubleVal: d) else {
        print("cannot be converted")
    }

    print("converted: \(intVal)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension Double {
  var prettyWeight: String {
    Int(exactly: self) == nil ? "\(self)kg" : "\(Int(self))kg"
  }
}
```

---

test result

```
for i in stride(from: 0.5, to: 10, by: 0.5) {
  print("\(i): \(i.prettyWeight)")
}

0.5: 0.5kg
1.0: 1kg
1.5: 1.5kg
2.0: 2kg
2.5: 2.5kg
3.0: 3kg
3.5: 3.5kg
4.0: 4kg
4.5: 4.5kg
5.0: 5kg
5.5: 5.5kg
6.0: 6kg
6.5: 6.5kg
7.0: 7kg
7.5: 7.5kg
8.0: 8kg
8.5: 8.5kg
9.0: 9kg
9.5: 9.5kg
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care for very large values use this code to clamp the `Doubl to max/min` Int` values.

```
let bigDouble   = Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude
let smallDouble = -bigDouble

extension Double {
    func toIntTruncated() -> Int {
        let maxTruncated  = min(self, Double(Int.max).nextDown) // Nota bene: crashes without `nextDown`
        let bothTruncated = max(maxTruncated, Double(Int.min))
        return Int(bothTruncated)
    }
}

let bigDoubleInt   = bigDouble.toIntTruncated()
let smalDoublelInt = smallDouble.toIntTruncated()
```