# Make double 0.93 to integer 93

Tags: swift, double

```
self.humidityLbl.text = "Humidity: \(self.currentWeather.humidity)%"
```

outputs `Humidity: 0.93%`. How can I convert double 0.93 to integer 93 in Swift?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert double to int in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915838/how-to-convert-double-to-int-in-swift)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `NumberFormatter` with `percent` style to present a percentage
value to the user. This will use the proper format for the user's
locale. Examples:

```
let humidity = 0.93

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .percent

formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en") // English
print(formatter.string(for: humidity)!) // 93%

formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "de") // German
print(formatter.string(for: humidity)!) // 93 %

formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "tr") // Turkish
print(formatter.string(for: humidity)!) // %93

formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ar") // Arabic
print(formatter.string(for: humidity)!) // ٩٣ ٪؜
```

Here I have set `formatter.locale` to different values for
demonstration purposes. If you don't assign a value, the user's
default settings are used.

Comment: This is the better answer and should be accepted instead of mine. I don't know why I didn't suggest the same thing. `NumberFormatter` is always the better choice when showing numbers to users.

Answer (score 4):

Simple. Multiply by 100 and convert to an `Int`.

```
self.humidityLbl.text = "Humidity: \(Int(self.currentWeather.humidity * 100))%"
```

If you want to get fancy, create a helper extension on `Double`:

```
extension Double {
    func percent() -> Int {
        return Int(self * 100)
    }
}

self.humidityLbl.text = "Humidity: \(self.currentWeather.humidity.percent())%"
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help and support!

Answer (score 0):

You can cast to `Int` after multiplying it by 100, but you can use NSNumber instead:

```
let intNumber = NSNumber.init(value: 0.93 * 100).intValue

print(intNumber)
```

I think this is a safer way.

Comment: In what way is this "safer"? Safer than what?

Comment: When you cast a double number that is larger than Int.max, you will see what happen :))

Comment: You should put that info in your answer. BTW - Your code would fail (give the wrong value) if the `NSNumber` contained a value too large for an `Int`. Of course the code in my answer will crash. But it is quite likely that it won't be an issue in this case.