# How to cast from Double to Int?

Tags: swift

Suppose I have a `Double` and I create an `Int` from the `Double`:

```
var a : Double = 4.0
var b = Int(a)
```

In the past, the above code could result in `b=3` if `a` was internally represented as `3.999999999999999`. Do we not have to worry about this anymore in Swift? What is the correct way to cast a Double to an Int?

Comment: if you are not talking about rounding, what is your question ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert double to int in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915838/how-to-convert-double-to-int-in-swift)

Comment: "What is the correct way to cast a Double to an Int?" that solely depends on your own requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You're using generic initializer [`init(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2883791-init) which creates an integer from the given floating-point value, rounding toward zero.

So, there is well known problem with saving types based on floating point math (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)). Because of that, your `a` can be saved for example as `3.99999999999999994`. Then, if you use this `Int` initalizer from this `Double`, it creates `Int` rounded toward zero... (`3`)

---

One way is rounding your `Double` value before it will be passed for `Int` initializer to one decimal place

```
round(a*10)/10
```

and then round result by following rule

```
>= 0.5  round up
< 0.5   round down
```

For this purpose you can use `rounded` method with `FloatingPointRoundingRule` `.toNearestOrAwayFromZero` (which is default value for this parameter)

```
var a: Double = 3.499999999
var b = Int((round(a*10)/10).rounded()) // b = 4
```

---

Also you can use failable initalizer, since if `Double` is bigger then `Int` can be, code crashes

```
var a: Double = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
if var b = Int(exactly: (round(a*10)/10).rounded()) { ... } // nil
```

Comment: My main question is, if I have an arbritary double, it could be represented as 3.99999999, 4.00000000, or 4.000000001, as examples. So I am looking for the proper way to do Double -> Int. I wasn't looking for a way to set a variable to 4!

Comment: @statguy There is no such thing as `proper way to do Double -> Int`. Pick a rounding method.

Comment: `.toNearestOrAwayFromZero` is the default rounding rule, you can simply write `Int(a.rounded())`

Comment: @MartinR right, thank you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
let roundedVal = round(a)
var b = Int(roundedVal)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use prototype `Double.rounded()` before casting it to Int. So a double number like `3.99999999999...` or `4.000000000001` becomes `4`:

```
var a : Double = 3.999999999999
var b = Int(a.rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero))
print(Int(a)) // output: 3
print(b) // output: 4
```